# How to make Flask accept JSON and store accepted JSON into DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, flask

I have working Flask route that can print accepted JSON (it is being sent as POST with BODY containing JSON).

```
@app.route('/json', methods=['POST']) 
def jsonify():
    json_dict = json.load(request.json)
    print ("\njson0:\n")
```

How to load it into DF?

Comment: I don't see your endpoint printing the given json. Also, `pandas` can read from a dictionary https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the content type as 'application/json' in your request. For example :

```
request.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=json.dumps({'text': 'Hello'})
```

Then in Flask you should use request.get_json() which is better than .json.

To load your json into a DF you can simply type :

```
 pd.DataFrame(json_dict)
```

Your json should be formated as `[{'name':'Jask','age':24},{'name':'Bob','age':30}]` for instance.

Comment: Thanks...  This helped.